# Sending Notification with Amazon SNS and Firebase FCM to Android app are not received when app is closed

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm sending notifications via `amazon sns` and `google Firebase fcm`.
Everything is working fine if the app is in the foreground or background.
But if the app is killed then notifications stop.

I get the following in the debug console

`W/GCM/DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=... (has extras) }`

I've look around for answers but found nothing?

Comment: check the answer of Teerakiat Chitawattanarat in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082). He discussed how to make firebase library to call `onMessageReceived()` in foreground, background or if the app has been killed.

Comment: this worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase